# A parameter to quantify instability in flight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, biophysics, statistics

Suppose I have plotted the body angles of a flying aeroplane.I have two such plots. One of a normal plane, and the other plot in which a primary sensor of the aeroplane is removed. So with the absence of a sensor you are expected to see an instability in their flight. Below are the two graphs--- The first one is the control flight, and the second one is the experimental (sensor removed.)

[image: Control]

[image: Sensor Removed]

Lets look at the second graph --- you can see that the roll of the flight is sinusoidal. Even the pitch is slightly. But the sinusoid fluctuation of the roll is more prominent. And I see this fluctuation in all my experimental graphs (sensor-removed) that I have obtained, and none in the control (normal) graphs.

Now, I would like to quantify this fluctuation. One way of quantifying it would be to plot the mean and standard deviation of roll in both cases and show that the standard deviation is very high in the second case. But this is not correct because, the standard deviation might also be very high in the first case ---- this can happen when the flight rolls a lot, but does not necessarily fluctuate. It could roll in one direction, maintain that for some time, then roll in the opposite direction or the same one. Its not fluctuating, but standard deviation will be high.

So, I am looking for another parameter, to quantify this fluctuation in the graph, something like a fourier transform perhaps. Something that would accentuate the instability bit. Suggestions people?

Answer (score 2):

In linear control systems theory one way control systems engineers model physical systems is by transforming the set of linear differential equations describing the system into the frequency domain. So using the LaPlace transform one winds up with a rational polynomial function that related some desired sets of system inputs and outputs. The benefit of using this approach is there is a well defined procedure for determining a stability margin for the closed loop system. The margins include gain, phase and delay margin - how much of each can be tolerated before the system becomes unstable.

One could attempt to model the flight dynamics as a linear transfer function (perhaps this already exists?) and from that you could analytically determine what your stability margins are.

The type of motion you see in your roll and pitch data appear to be a 'stable oscillation' otherwise known as a limit cycle. Limit cycles normally cannot exist in the domain of linear systems theory but rather require a non-linearity, so I'm assuming the aeroplane has some form of a 'backup system' that takes over after the primary sensor based system has failed to maintain stable attitude. This backup system could, for example, be another system doing the same job, maybe with a higher latency. There are ways to analyze limit cycle behavior, but it requires more complex modeling.

But I believe you may be looking for a simpler, more practical way to measure stability. So here's an idea. Again, the rolling and pitching oscillations occur by brief periods of divergence. But eventually this leads to the backup system reversing the motions. And its the two behaviors that are probably leading to the limit cycle. One way to measure the 'strength' of the limit cycle is simply by its amplitude or else peak to peak size. Could this serve as your stability measure?

Comment: docscience, could you let me know once you've had a chance to review the edited version of this answer? (just ping me in a comment here)

Comment: @David Z "divergent" should be either "divergent behavior" or more simply "divergence". And you've removed some content that I orginally wrote that describes the existence of a backup system, so the third paragraph has lost meaning. I believe its the primary system that's using the halteres that's gone unstable, but something else prevents the fly from going into a complete tumble. My speculation is that might be vision, but regardless there is something - unless perhaps the complete organ (haltere) was NOT removed?

Comment: I wasn't the one who edited, I just wanted to make sure you'd seen it and had a chance to make any corrections you see fit. (It is ultimately up to you to correct the answer as needed, since it's your post.)

Comment: @Black Dagger My speculation is the backup system might be vision, but regardless there is something - unless perhaps the organ (haltere) was NOT completely removed and is still providing partial functionality?

Comment: @docscience I have reframed the question. Instead of a 'fly' it's an 'aeroplane' now. And instead of 'haltere' it's 'primary sensor'. I request you to please remove these words('fly' & 'haltere') from the above comments. I have re-edited your answer as well. Once you remove those words I'll delete this comment as well. I have reframed the question as well.